# How can I make a pipe from a command line argument?

Tags: c, pipe

I am working on a project that is to take in a file name(s) from the command line, up to four and my goal is to store them in the 2D array `pipes[4][2]` and then create a pipe for each of those filenames. I am not able to get the command line arguments into the array and in turn set up a pipe. What am I doing wrong? This is the code I have so far

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    int pipes [4][2];
    if (argc > 5){
        printf("Fail");
        exit(2);
    }
    else if (argc < 2){
        printf("Fail");
        exit(3);
    }
    else
    { 
        int argCount;
        if(argc == 2){
            argCount = 1;
         }
        else if(argc == 3){
            argCount = 2;
         }
        else if( argc == 4){
            argCount = 3;
         }
        else if(argc == 5) {
            argCount = 4;
         }
        for(int i=1; argCount >= i; i++){
           pipes[i] = argv[i];
           pipe(pipes[i]);          
         }
    }
    return(0);
}
```

Comment: You want to 1) store the filenames in an array, and 2) create a pipe for each filename. Which part is giving you trouble?

Comment: Storing the items in the array? As you see in the for loop I have pipes[I] = argv[I]; but it does not seem to be storing the command line argument in the array. Do I need to have it set up a different way?

Comment: (Probably) unrelated to your problem, but - the whole if / else part assigning `argCount` should be replaced with `int argCount = argc - 1;`.

Comment: Thank you, that makes more sense to do it like that. Is how I have the pipes[I]=argv[I] actually putting each argument into the array?

Comment: @iueass: first you create a 2-dimensional array `int pipes [4][2];` but then you try to use only one dimension ? `pipes[i] = argv[i];` I don't know if it compiles at all, but even if it does you shouldn't do that.

Comment: Either actually use the 2D array, or else just make it a 1D array instead.

Comment: Programmer, thank you that helped and I am actually adding the items to the array, if I could ask, now that I have them added to the array like this pipes[i][2] == argv[I]; Is the correct way to make a pipe for each of them like this? (In the same for loop, pipe(pipes[i][2]);

Comment: This makes little sense. In `pipes[i] = argv[i];`  you are attempting to assign a pointer-to-string to an integer array. Your compiler should be firmly reporting an error here, something akin to *"error: array type 'int [2]' is not assignable"*. Regardless, `pipe` *initializes* an `int [2]`, so these would-be values are irrelevant, as the call will overwrite any existing data in the array. What are you actually trying to do here? It is not clear. Unnamed pipes have no notion of "file name(s)", so what is the correlation between these would-be pipes and your program arguments?

Comment: @Oka thank you for the response. The goal is to take in up to 4 command line args and then store them in the 2D array and then use pipe to create a pipe for each of them. After that I plan to use exec ls-l on them and send the results to the child process.

Comment: Any reason not to just set `int argCount = argc - 1;` ?? With `int pipes [4][2];` how do you expect to make `pipes[i] = argv[i];` where one is type `int*` and the other type `char*`? What happens if `argcount >= 4` in the loop `for(int i=1; argCount >= i; i++){`? Would that make `pipes[i]` access beyond the array bounds for `i == 4`? (valid indexes are `0` to `3` for the first level of indirection...)

Comment: Good general discussion of [Pipes and FIFOs](https://ftp.gnu.org/old-gnu/Manuals/glibc-2.2.3/html_chapter/libc_15.html). It is unclear how you want to use the names read from the command line unless they are the names of *named-pipes* (FIFOs). If you want to both read and write to the files named on the command line and they are not special FIFOs, you simply need to open the files in read/write mode (no pipes required).